# Is there a way to block flask migrations from accessing some schemas?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I have 2 schemas that Admin and Ruby and for the migrations to work I have to use the parameter `include_schemas=True` but I have other schemas that are created by the google cloud SQL system that can't be changed but the `flask DB upgrade` command is trying to drop tables from there so my question is if there is a way for me to either include the two schemas `Ruby and Admin` or exclude the system managed ones.

My configuration for flask migrate:

```
migrate = Migrate(app, db, include_schemas=True, version_table_schema='Admin')
```

The error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1227, 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation')
[SQL: 
DROP TABLE performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)
```

Please don't comment saying for me to give `SUPER privilege` to the app since I don't want it to delete does system managed schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a new function in `migrations/env.py`:

The code:

```
def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    if type_ == 'table' and object.schema != 'Ruby' or object.schema != 'Admin':
        return False

     return True
```

and adding this parameter to the `context.configure`:

```
include_object=include_object
```